# Project file contains ToolsVersion="4.0", which is not supported by this version of MSBuild

Tags: visual-studio

How do I get rid of this error, I am using Visual Studio 2008 because 2010 wouldn't open some of my VB Projects.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

A VS2008 project file starts out with

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="3.5" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
```

where the ToolsVersion indicates the .net framework tools version.  VS2010 uses .net 4, so clearly has made the corresponding change in its tools version.

I would expect that opening your project files in Notepad and resetting the tools version to 3.5 will clear that issue.  Whether there are other backwards incompatibilities lurking, I couldn't say.

Comment: I can confirm this was the case for me.

Answer (score 1):

change the target framework to 3.5

in `project settings --> compile -->more options--> target framework`

Answer (score 0):

Install Visual studio 2008 SP1,It will be ok!